# How can I make my proxy server use a proxy to access another proxy

Tags: proxy, squid, privoxy

I need to set up a HTTP proxy server (call it server `A`) for users to access Internet. For some reason, it needs to forward all the requests to another HTTP proxy server (call it server `C`). But `C` is not directly accessible by `A`, unless by using another HTTP proxy server `B`.

```
User --> A --> B --> C
```

Proxy server `A` and `C` is controlled by me and I can install anything or configure anything on them. But `B` is a existing HTTP transparent proxy which I cannot control or configure.

I don't know which software can support this kind of "proxy chaining forwarding".

Do `squid` or `privoxy` or other software support this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try to Squid [cache_peer](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_peer/).

First, add C:

```
cache_peer C_ADDRESS parent 8080 0 no-query no-digest
never_direct allow all
```

Then try change cache_peer to B address:

```
cache_peer B_ADDRESS parent 8080 0 no-query no-digest
never_direct allow all
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they both support proxy chains. Ooshro has already [explained](https://serverfault.com/questions/240069/how-can-i-make-my-proxy-server-use-a-proxy-to-access-another-proxy/240075#240075) how you can do it in squid. In privoxy you can do it by [forwarding](https://serverfault.com/questions/240069/how-can-i-make-my-proxy-server-use-a-proxy-to-access-another-proxy/240075#240075).